# Why aren't my LEDs turning on while using Proteus?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, comparator, proteus, lm386

I'm trying to simulate an audio vumeter, using an audio amplifier built with a LM386. However, when I connect the output of the signal to the input of one of the opamps (I'm using LM358), the outputs are all negative.

[image: Here is the circuit before the simulation]

[image: Here is the circuit while simulation is running]

Comment: Positive (non-inverting) input of all opamps are tied together, but they're not tied to any known voltage source.  i.e. they're all "floating"

Comment: You forgot to connect 'Vout' over to all the opamps.

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending any voltage signal to the comparators. Thus they won't show anything with no input.